# Order of execution in nested loops in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I cant understand the difference between those two code blocks, first the correct one is:

```
number_list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
prime_list=[]
for i in number_list:
    for j in range(2,i):
        if i%j==0:
            break
    else: prime_list.append(i)
print('Primes are:',prime_list)
```

Output is:

```
Primes are: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
```

but moving the else statement forward inside the block below the if statement (which i thought was the right thing to do) results in a different and wrong output:

```
number_list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
prime_list=[]
for i in number_list:
    for j in range(2,i):
        if i%j==0:
            break
        else: prime_list.append(i)
print('Primes are:',prime_list)
```

Output is:

```
Primes are: [3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13]
```

Why is this so? how does the code behave with the else statement indented?

Comment: Suppose I is 6 ok and you will check with 2,3,4,5 and it will give 0,0,2,1 as mod value now if you put else inside it will append each time when it will not be 0 so for 4,5 it will add in the prime list!! Change your condition in which you are appending do it if i%j is not 0 then you add it else do nothing

Comment: In the first example, the else-statement belongs to the inner for-loop. In this case, `i` is appended to `prime_list` after the inner for-loop has finished iterating  through range `(2,i)`. In the second case, the else-statement belongs to the if-statement. In this case, `i` is appended to `prime_list` every time `i%j != 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example `else` is used for: `for` loop. It means that the code inside `else` statement is executed only if `for loop` ends without `break`.
So in your case only of any number from the range `(2, i)` is not a divider of `i`.

In the second case `else` is used for: `if` statement. It means that: if `if` is not true, then execute `else` statement. In this scenario let's assume `i=5`. For:

```
j = 2 => i%j = 1 => else statement is executed:  prime_list.append(5)
j = 3 => i%j = 2 => else statement is executed:  prime_list.append(5)
j = 4 => i%j = 1 => else statement is executed:  prime_list.append(5)
```

And thats why you have 3 times `5` in your list.

Answer (score 1):

The else in different scope has difference means:

1. else with the same scope of your for-loop is the else condition. It will be execute when not-break in your for loop.
2. else in the for-loop is used to exit the for loop in your second case. The else is related on your if statement

Answer (score 0):

Because when moving in, it will loop and most of the case exit the first `if` statement, then since the `else` says to add the value, it would keep adding to it.

There is other ways to do this and more efficiently, like below:

```
prime_list=[i for i in number_list if all(i % x for x in range(2, i))][1:]
print('Primes are:',prime_list)
```